# Is a source code heavily based on re-frame expected to have direct calls (or mentions) to app-db?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, data-driven, re-frame

I have been using Clojure, ClojureScript, lein, shadow-cljs, Emacs, and CIDER to work on a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project.

The project heavily uses [Re-frame](https://day8.github.io/re-frame/subscriptions/). According to the official documentation, everything is on the data-driven architecture.

> A UI is just derived data.

> A browser renders tree-shaped data called the DOM. Reagent renderers create DOM by computing hiccup-shaped data. Subscriptions deliver data to Reagent renderers. And, app-db is the root of this entire flow.

Hence, I was expecting direct calls to `app-db` on the project. Or at least some mention on the source code. However, there **is not a single direct call or mention of any kind** to `app-db`. I must highlight that this is a large and professional project being used by paid customers.

Is this behavior expected? Is it a good (or the only possible) practice?

Are only `reg-sub` and `subscribe` the ways to indirectly access `app-db`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are not expected to touch `app-db` directly. All `re-frame` functions use it internally and you should use those.